# Fazer pesquisa no banco em tempo real

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax, banco-de-dados

Como eu posso fazer no PHP para que quando o usuário digitar no campo de pesquisa ele já apareça os registros do banco de dados.

Por exemplo, supondo que seja um cadastro de cidades, o usuário digita "Campo", deve aparecer os registros "Campo Grande, Campo Largo, Campo Mourão..." de forma imediata, no ato da digitação.

É muito complexo fazer isso?

Comment: Isso que você quer é AJAX

Comment: Você precisa utilizar Ajax. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_php.asp

Comment: E como fazer para que o resultado da pesquisa seja um dropdown e que usuário clique no resultado para que preencha o campo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode chamar via ajax o resultado e criar uma lista de autocomplete utilizando o componente [Vanilla Javascript AutoComplete](https://goodies.pixabay.com/javascript/auto-complete/demo.html)

Você vai dar o autocomplete no retorno da chamada em Javascript:

```
function ShowModalRelMapaAeronave() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: BASE_SITE + '/Projeto/Projeto/BuscarAeronaves',
        data: {  },
        success: function (data) {

            new autoComplete({
                selector: '#TxtAeronave',
                minChars: 2,
                source: function (term, suggest) {
                    term = term.toLowerCase();
                    var choices = data;
                    var matches = [];
                    for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++)
                        if (~choices[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) matches.push(choices[i]);
                    suggest(matches);
                }
            });

            $('#modalRelMapaAeronave').modal('show');
        }
    });
}
```

Aqui no caso chamo o post em um rota, pego o retorno e coloco em um txt do meu html, assim quando ele vai digitando vai autocompletando. É necessário adicionar o javascript e css da biblioteca.

A rota fica responsável por fazer a consulta.

Comment: +1 pela lib, isso quebra um bom galho